# BlockHound throws blocking call exception when using bean validation in Webflux

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux

I tested BlockHound on our Spring Boot 2.1.8 application with Webflux and I encountered a blocking call inside bean validation. To make sure that's for sure not caused by our logic I created simple Webflux app with one endpoint.

That's a simple controller from the app:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/test")
@Validated
class TestController {

    @PostMapping("/{type}", consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
    fun testPost(@PathVariable type: String, @Valid @RequestBody entry: TestEntry): Mono<TestEntry> {
        return Mono.just(TestEntry("${entry.data} - $type"))
    }
}

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
data class TestEntry(
    @field:NotNull val data: String?
)
```

And in the main method I run Block Hound JVM agent:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class DemoApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    BlockHound.install()

    runApplication<DemoApplication>(*args)
}
```

After sending request to my endpoint I get this exception:

```
java.lang.Error: Blocking call! java.io.RandomAccessFile#readBytes
    at reactor.blockhound.BlockHound$Builder.lambda$new$0(BlockHound.java:196) ~[blockhound-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/v1/test/type1" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
        at reactor.blockhound.BlockHound$Builder.lambda$new$0(BlockHound.java:196) ~[blockhound-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at reactor.blockhound.BlockHound$Builder.lambda$install$6(BlockHound.java:318) ~[blockhound-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at reactor.blockhound.BlockHoundRuntime.checkBlocking(BlockHoundRuntime.java:46) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.readBytes(RandomAccessFile.java) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.read(RandomAccessFile.java:406) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.readFully(RandomAccessFile.java:470) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.readFullyAt(ZipFile.java:1298) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.initDataOffset(ZipFile.java:997) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:1012) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:467) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:159) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.io.InputStream.readNBytes(InputStream.java:490) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:805) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.checkForSpecialAttributes(JarFile.java:1005) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.isMultiRelease(JarFile.java:388) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.getEntry(JarFile.java:507) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getEntry(URLJarFile.java:131) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:137) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:155) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1117) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(ClassLoader.java:1738) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getResourceAsStream(Class.java:2651) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.inspectClass(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:94) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1705) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.doGetParameterNames(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:84) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:72) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer.java:55) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean$1.getParameterNames(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:325) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.ExecutableParameterNameProvider.getParameterNames(ExecutableParameterNameProvider.java:37) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.18.Final.jar:6.0.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.aggregated.ParameterMetaData$Builder.build(ParameterMetaData.java:169) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.18.Final.jar:6.0.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.aggregated.ExecutableMetaData$Builder.findParameterMetaData(ExecutableMetaData.java:435) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.18.Final.jar:6.0.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.aggregated.ExecutableMetaData$Builder.build(ExecutableMetaData.java:388) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.18.Final.jar:6.0.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.aggregated.BeanMetaDataImpl$BuilderDelegate.build(BeanMetaDataImpl.java:788) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.18.Final.jar:6.0.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.aggregated.BeanMetaDataImpl$BeanMetaDataBuilder.build(BeanMetaDataImpl.java:648) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.18.Final.jar:6.0.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.BeanMetaDataManager.createBeanMetaData(BeanMetaDataManager.java:204) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.18.Final.jar:6.0.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.BeanMetaDataManager.getBeanMetaData(BeanMetaDataManager.java:166) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.18.Final.jar:6.0.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValueContext.getLocalExecutionContext(ValueContext.java:78) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.18.Final.jar:6.0.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateReturnValueInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:1060) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.18.Final.jar:6.0.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateReturnValue(ValidatorImpl.java:306) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.18.Final.jar:6.0.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateReturnValue(ValidatorImpl.java:257) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.18.Final.jar:6.0.18.Final]
        at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:122) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at com.example.demo.TestController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ae3498ec.testPost(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.InvocableHandlerMethod.lambda$invoke$0(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:147) ~[spring-webflux-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:118) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1630) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.signal(MonoZip.java:247) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onNext(MonoZip.java:329) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:173) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:92) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:192) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:73) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1630) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:287) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:330) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1630) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:145) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:252) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.terminateReceiver(FluxReceive.java:419) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.2.RELEASE.jar:0.9.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:209) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.2.RELEASE.jar:0.9.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:367) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.2.RELEASE.jar:0.9.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:363) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.2.RELEASE.jar:0.9.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onInboundNext(HttpServerOperations.java:461) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.2.RELEASE.jar:0.9.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:89) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.2.RELEASE.jar:0.9.2.RELEASE]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler.channelRead(HttpTrafficHandler.java:211) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.2.RELEASE.jar:0.9.2.RELEASE]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:438) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:326) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:300) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:253) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1422) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:931) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:700) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:635) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:552) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:514) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1050) ~[netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Is there a way to *unblock* somehow this validation?

EDIT:

Seems like hibernate bean validation is blocking. One of the solution which I've found it's creating custom [spring Validator](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-fn-handler-validation). In my case it'd be something like that:

```
@Component
class TestEntryValidator: Validator {
    override fun validate(target: Any, errors: Errors) {
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(
            errors, "data", "field.required")
    }

    override fun supports(clazz: Class<*>): Boolean {
        return TestEntry::class.javaObjectType.isAssignableFrom(clazz)
    }
}
```

It usage could look like that:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/test")
class TestController(val testSpringValidator: TestEntryValidator) {

    @PostMapping("/{type}", consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
    fun testPost(@PathVariable type: String, @RequestBody entry: TestEntry): Mono<TestEntry> {
        return Mono.fromCallable {
            val errors = BeanPropertyBindingResult(
                entry,
                TestEntry::class.java.name
            )
            testSpringValidator.validate(entry, errors)

            if (errors.allErrors.isEmpty()) {
                TestEntry("${entry.data} - $type")
            } else {
                throw ResponseStatusException(
                    HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
                    errors.allErrors.toString()
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

data class TestEntry(
    val data: String?
)
```

Unfortunately that forces you to add some additional boilerplate code but I haven't found anything better for now.

Comment: since you havnt posted anything about what validation that is being used or anything, no one will help you. The validation library you are using is reading some bytes from somewhere. So you are probably using a blocking validation library.

Comment: I don't use any custom bean validation. I use hibernate-validator:6.0.17 which is included in spring-boot-starter-webflux. Are there any nonblocking alternatives? I thought that Webflux should provide nonblocking libs OOTB.

Comment: post your full code, are you reading in parameters/properties

Comment: It's all code. I created new Webflux app using spring initializr and added this one ednpoint and blockhound dependency.

Comment: After further investigation, I noticed that method `PlatformResourceBundleLocator.loadBundle` in _hibernate_ is blocking. I also tried _bval_ from Apache and it blocks on `ConstraintDefaults.loadProperties`.

Comment: Have you tried to see if only blocks on the first call, and then it caches the properties

Comment: Yeah it caches it indeed. Weird thing is that when I post valid payload and then repead it, everything is ok. But then I violate constraint it blocks. Maybe there is a way to precache these properties?

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-resource-bundle-locator explains it, it loads custom validation messages that you can store in resource bundles. If there are multiple resource bundles it will aggregate them. It probably first loads a default bundle, then it loads bundle containing all the error msgs

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue. It's not clear to me if the issue is with hibernate or with Spring WebFlux. I resolved it for now by reverting to javax.validation 2.0.1 and using bval-jsr instead of hibernate.

Answer (score 7):

I was experimenting the same behavior in my Spring Boot application. The good news is that it is very easy to solve.

When you use validation annotations, when a field fail the constraint, the message to notice that is loaded from file. That is blocking!

So, the only you have to do is to provide a message to show, instead of read the default value from file.

For example, if you want to restrict a String field with not blank values,
use this

```
@NotBlank(message = "Field must not be blank")
private String mandatoryField;
```

istead of this

```
@NotBlank
private String mandatoryField;
```

That's all!

Comment: Repeating this message in every annotation doesn't look like the right solution.

Comment: Of course, you can extract the message text to a constant if the text is exactly the same in many cases

Comment: And what about if you need i18n?

Comment: I think you can externalize the messages (properties or yaml files) and load the right value dinamically

Comment: @Alberthoven that would cause the same initial problem that is provide the annotation without a message.

Comment: Right. Maybe you could load an static structure (2-dimensional map or something similar, bein the country the first level and the message ley the second)